# Creating a container under a private storage account in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-sdk

I have a storage account created for an AKS cluster, which is configured with a private endpoint. Public access is denied on it.
There is a client service installed in the same network as the cluster, which is trying to create a container within this storage account.
Here is the code snippet:

```
c, err: = azblob.NewSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey)
if err != nil {
    return azblob.ContainerURL {}, err
}
p: = azblob.NewPipeline(c, azblob.PipelineOptions {
    Telemetry: azblob.TelemetryOptions {
        Value: "test-me"
    },
})
u, err: = url.Parse(fmt.Sprintf(blobFormatString, accountName))
if err != nil {
    return azblob.ContainerURL {}, err
}
service: = azblob.NewServiceURL( * u, p)
container: = service.NewContainerURL(containerName)
c, err: = GetContainerURL(a.Log, ctx, a.SubscriptionID, a.ClientID, a.ClientSecret, a.TenantID, a.StorageAccount, accountKey, a.ResourceGroup, a.Bucket)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
_, err = c.GetProperties(ctx, azblob.LeaseAccessConditions {})
if err != nil {
    if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "ContainerNotFound") {
        _, err = c.Create(
            ctx,
            azblob.Metadata {},
            azblob.PublicAccessContainer)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
}
```

This code when executed throws an error like:

> Details: \n   Code: PublicAccessNotPermitted\n   PUT [https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername?restype=container&timeout=61\n](https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername?restype=container&timeout=61%5Cn)   Authorization: REDACTED
> RESPONSE Status: 409 Public access is not permitted on this storage account

Should not the container creation be completed, since the client is already on the cluster. What is it that i am doing wrong?

Many thanks!!

Comment: are you sure your client is using the private endpoint connection? doesnt look like it. Do a nslookup on the storage FQDN from your client machine

Comment: How could i verify that, is there someplace in the UI/CLI that i could see the private endpoint to be used?

Comment: The error suggests that it’s not being used. Ideally you would run nslookup and see a private IP address being returned

Comment: The url im using is "https: //storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net" referenced by [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints#connecting-to-a-private-endpoint)
Should i be using the private IP for this?

Comment: Yes, for your client that should resolve to a private IP, not a public IP

Comment: Hi @J.Cage, if the provided answer resolved your issue, you may mark it as answer or upvote it so that others who encounter the similar issue, it may be useful for them or community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Details: \n Code: PublicAccessNotPermitted\n PUT [https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername?restype=container&timeout=61\n](https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername?restype=container&timeout=61%5Cn) Authorization: REDACTED RESPONSE Status: 409 Public access is not permitted on this storage account

•   The error code that you are interacting with clearly states that **‘public access is not permitted on your storage account’**, i.e., either the ***private endpoint connection that you have configured on your storage account is not configured properly and the account is not secured by configuring the storage firewall to block all connections on the public endpoint for the storage service***.

•   Thus, I would suggest you **increase the security for the virtual network (VNET), by enabling you to block the exfiltration of data from the VNET**. Also, `securely connect to storage accounts from on-premises networks that connect to the VNET using VPN or ExpressRoutes with private-peering`.

•   Also, please ensure that the **IP address that is assigned to the private endpoint is an IP address from the address range of the VNET** and it is **excluded from any restrictions in the network security group or AKS ingress controller or the Azure Firewall**.

•   Finally, ***ensure that the private endpoints provisioned for the storage account are not general-purpose v1 storage accounts as private endpoints for these storage accounts are not permitted***. Also, configure the storage firewall for the storage account as described in the documentation link below: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#change-the-default-network-access-rule***

To know more about the details regarding the **configuration of private endpoints for storage accounts**, kindly refer to the documentation link below: -

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints**

Comment: There was an issue in the configuration of the endpoint. Thanks.